# If a nations laws are immoral in the face of Torah laws, are we still obligated to abide by them?

Tags: politics-government

Let me be clear, I'm not advocating breaking any laws.  lol

Say, for example, a country makes it a crime to keep kosher or wear head coverings inside buildings.

Throughout history we've been forced to assimilate through laws that force conversion, or laws that make Shabbat illegal, and etc so there exists a precedence.

Are we obligated to follow such laws?  If so, then to what extent?  And if not, does an alternative exist to fleeing the country?

Comment: The previous question was ambiguous to those of us who don't know the Hebrew terms.  Unfortunately, the previous question did not have any answers, nor was it as clear as this one.  And the difference is that I asked for answers for what to do.

Comment: I expected from the title for this to be a more halakhicly ambiguous case, like bankruptcy law, which from a halakhic perspective is theft in that you don't repay your loans, but from a legal perspective is an exemption from repaying them.